# Are whitespaces allowed after the forward slash of a HTML tag

Tags: html, whitespace

Is it legal to have whitespace after the forward slash of a closing HTML tag, like:
`</   script>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **invalid**, you can try the below code in validator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script src="#"></ script>
   </head>
   <body>
      Test
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not valid in any version of HTML. More importantly, the construct is not recognized as an end tag, or as a tag at all. In HTML parsing (as opposite to genuine XHTML), this means that the end of the `script` element is not seen, and if there is later a `script` element with a proper end tag, its end tag will be taken as terminating the first element. Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<title> </title>
<script>
var foo = 42
</ script>
<script>
alert('hi')
</script>
<script>
alert('hi again')
</script>
```

This will only display “hi again”, since the first `script` element is taken as containing the following, which, when run, will terminate in an error:

```
var foo = 42
</ script>
<script>
alert('hi')
```

Answer (score -2):

yes, it is allowed. It will be ignored.

Comment: While some browsers my ignore it. That doesnt make it allowed. It is invalid HTML